# Hidden Markov Model & Its Application

Tags: statistics, r

I have started reading about HMM it gives an intuitive idea about what HMM is all about. I am looking out for example where its applied to Equity model using R / Excel. The material which I read so far is about its application to speech recognition.

Comment: Am curious about this too as I am working on HMM right now, interesting question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Systematic Investor also did a two part series implementation in R which is also quite helpful as he details the pitfalls too.

Post One:
http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/regime-detection/

Part Two:
http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/regime-detection-pitfalls/

Updated version after the 'RHmm' library was taken down from CRAN repository:
http://systematicinvestor.github.io/Regime-Detection-Update

Answer (score 17):

The clearest and most intuitive article I have seen so far is 
[Kritzman et al., Regime Shifts: Implications for Dynamic Strategies in FAJ (May / June 2012)](http://www.cfapubs.org/doi/abs/10.2469/faj.v68.n3.3)

It not only shows how you can use HMM for financial modelling but it also goes through the actual estimation algorithm (Baum-Welch) step-by-step and even gives full MATLAB-code.

From the abstract:

> Regime shifts present significant challenges for investors because
>   they cause performance to depart significantly from the ranges implied
>   by long-term averages of means and covariances. But regime shifts also
>   present opportunities for gain. The authors show how to apply
>   Markov-switching models to forecast regimes in market turbulence,
>   inflation, and economic growth. They found that a dynamic process
>   outperformed static asset allocation in backtests, especially for
>   investors who seek to avoid large losses.

I brought the paper to the attention of the renowned blog [Quantivity](http://quantivity.wordpress.com/) and they started a series on reproducing the results in R: [Here](http://quantivity.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/multi-asset-market-regimes/).

(I am not aware of a freely accessible copy of the paper - if you find one, please include it in a comment - I will change the answer accordingly.)

For your own experiments with HMM in R you can use the [RHmm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHmm/index.html).

**Addendum**
Unfortunately the RHmm package has been deprecated. A good alternative seems to be the [depmixS4 package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depmixS4/index.html).

Comment: This is very nice

Comment: Free link to the [paper](http://www.statestreetglobalmarkets.com/wps/wcm/connect/a3c597004e65ffd19c00fe2a1fc2916b/FAJ_MJ12_Kritzman_Page_Turkington+(2).pdf?MOD=AJPERES).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the following two papers, one from Chris Rogers and Liang Zhang where they introduce a model using HMM which captures stylized facts of financial returns. And the second where we extended this model to risk measures.

Implementation in R is strait forward using ML as mentioned in the paper.

http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~chris/papers/UAR.pdf

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.4126.pdf