# Asset allocation problem using Hidden Markov Model

Tags: r, optimization, matlab, asset-allocation, hidden-markov-model

I am recently getting more interested in Hidden Markov Models (HMM) and its application on financial assets to understand their behavior. But what captured my attention the most is the use of asset regimes as information to portfolio optimization problem.
I am refering to this  [article](http://www.sandpointe.com/pdf/dynamic-asset-allocation-for-regime-switching-framework.pdf.pdf)
I searched in many sites  for the code to apply an asset allocation problem based on HMM estimations but I can't find ..
I am extremely interesed ..I would be very grateful if you could provide me any code example that uses HMM to asset allocation problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, do you want references to papers applying HMM to asset allocation?

Comment: No, I am searching for program code to apply HMM to asset allocation problem

Comment: So you would like the code that implements the method described in the article?

Comment: If it possible, if not, I would be grateful if you could give me any similar code example

Comment: I'm not really a fan of this type of question as if the code exists the answer will just be a link to some source code. I'm not sure this fits the format. I've created a [discussion](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/1496/848) and I'm hoping for community input.

Comment: You are linking to a pirated paper, which is frowned upon here. Would you please provide a link to a place where you can get the paper legally - Thank you.

Comment: But then you have code examples? So what is your question then?

Comment: just for reference: I involuntarily deleted the link so here it is again: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4852/hidden-markov-model-its-application

Comment: I need code example that uses HMM to asset allocation problem, namely, how to optimize a portfolio taking into accout asset regimes identifed by the HMM.

Comment: Ok, see my answer for a basic approach: http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/28349/12

Answer (score 3):

The basic approach is as follows:

When you estimate the HMM you estimate three things:

1. When you are in which state
2. The drifts of your assets
3. The covariance matrices of your assets

You would then take 2. and 3. for each state (1.) and feed it into your favourite allocation optimizer to estimate your optimal portfolio for each state.

Voila!

Comment: @NourhaineNefzi: Thank you. If it was helpful it is appreciated if you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find anything. Why don't you contact the authors? They must have some code to generate the HMM simulations in the paper, maybe they can share the code with you?

Have you checked the Supplementary Materials? Some papers have it.

If you're really determined, you can implement a HMM model yourself. You'll need to supply the Markov transition model (included in the paper), then use the EM algorithm to fit a model. Python scikit-learn has a module for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. In fact, I am not familiar with codes, fortunately, there are packages developed in R and Matlab to train HMM .. but still don't know the technique to apply HMM to asset allocation problem .. I contacted the authors but I didn't get an answer.. thank you again for your care

Comment: @NourhaineNefzi Unless you have very good reason, I don't think it's a good idea to try to reproduce the paper. You don't have the data set they used, you don't know how exactly they derived the diagrams, etc. Do you have a supervisor (like professor) who can guide you about your problem?

Comment: I am PhD student in Finance, I want to get a code example so I can apply it to the context of the research..unfortunately my supervisor can't help

Comment: @NourhaineNefzi Your best bet is email the authors (all of them, not just one), and remind them if they don't respond you.

Comment: @NourhaineNefzi As a PhD student, I would suggest trying to understand it. Assuming you've already fit the HMM, you just get the mean and covariance matrix and the rest of it is just normal portfolio optimization.

Comment: @John: exactly, pls. see my answer. http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/28349/12

Comment: I don't want to optimize a portfolio in each regime .. I need to optimize one portfolio based on HMM regimes ( as information).. in the paper for example, they generated scenarios based on HMM probabilities ..

Comment: @NourhaineNefzi I just looked over the paper. They use a stochastic programming approach. If you're trying to learn it, I would suggest a simpler approach first. When you understand multi-period portfolio optimization you can do that. This is a paper that uses single-period optimization, for reference: https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/aang/papers/inquire.pdf